# is there a way to recover partially received contact files from bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I recently bought a new Galaxy s5 phone. when I tried to Bluetooth my contacts over, it only partially sent the file is there a way to open the partially send file?

Answer (score 0):

What phone are you sending the contacts from? If the phone is older, and especially if it's not Android, the files are most likely not compatible. You'll be better transferring the contacts via the Internet, if possible. You can use either Google account and sync your contacts with it, or use one of those sites dedicated to backing-up and transferring contacts.